# Sending data between components using a service in Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-services

I'm trying to send data between two components using a service. However, I'm having trouble with the data populating when the 'child' component first loads.

When you select a 'release' from the unordered list on the release-list.component, it will load the release-detail.component through a router-outlet. The release-detail.component should show the release artist.

It works if you select a release and then select a release for a second time. But I'm having to 'load' the release-detail.component twice before the data is populated. I feel I'm close but I must be missing something. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

I've referred to both a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39834286/components-communication-through-router-outlet) and the [Angular documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service)

release.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';

import { MockReleaseList, ReleaseInterface } from './mock-releases';

@Injectable()

export class ReleaseService {
    private releaseSubject$ = new Subject();

    getReleases(): ReleaseInterface[] {
        return MockReleaseList;
    }

    getRelease() {
        return this.releaseSubject$;
    }

    updateRelease(release: {artist: string, title: string, category: string}[]) {
        // console.log(release);
        this.releaseSubject$.next(release);
    }

}
```

release-list.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Location } from '@angular/common';

import { ReleaseService } from '../../../shared/services/release.service';
import { MockReleaseList, ReleaseInterface } from '../../../shared/services/mock-releases';

@Component({
  selector: 'ostgut-releases',
  template: `
    <h3>Label List</h3>
    <ul>
        <li *ngFor="let release of releases" (click)="onSelect(release)">{{ release.artist }}</li>
    </ul>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  `,
})
export class ReleaseListComponent implements OnInit { 
    private releases: ReleaseInterface[];

    constructor (
        private _router: Router,
        private _releaseService: ReleaseService
    ) {}

    ngOnInit(): ReleaseInterface[] {
        return this.releases = this._releaseService.getReleases();
    }

    onSelect(release: any): void {
        this._releaseService.updateRelease(release);
        this._router.navigate(['/release-list/release-detail', release.category]);
    }

}
```

release-detail.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

import { Router, ActivatedRoute, Params } from '@angular/router';

import { ReleaseService } from '../../../../shared/services/release.service';
import { ReleaseInterface } from '../../../../shared/services/mock-releases';

@Component({
  selector: 'ostgut-release-detail',
  template: `
    <h3>Release Detail</h3>
    <p>{{ release.artist }}</p>
  `,
})
export class ReleaseDetailComponent implements OnInit { 
    private routeParam: string;
    private routeParamSub: any;
    private release: any;

    constructor(
        private _activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
        private _router: Router,
        private _releaseService: ReleaseService
    ) {}

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.release = this._releaseService.getRelease().subscribe(release=>{
            return this.release = release;
        });
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem could be that your `Subject` publishes its value before you are subscribing to it inside your `ReleaseDetailComponent`. When you do it the second time, a new `Release` is published, and the `ReleaseDetailComponent` is already created - meaning it will work.

To fix this, you can try to use a `BehaviorSubject` instead of a regular `Subject` in your service. The `BehaviorSubject` will give you the latest published value even if you subscribe to it after the last value was published. It also expects a default value though, so you might want to add some null-checking in your `ReleaseDetailComponent` template.

An implementation could look something like this:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject'; // <-- note the import!

import { MockReleaseList, ReleaseInterface } from './mock-releases';

@Injectable()

export class ReleaseService {
    private releaseSubject$ = new BehaviorSubject(undefined);

   // The rest is the same

}
```

And in your template, att null checking, as the default value we set to the `BehaviorSubject` is `undefined`. Of course, you can set the default value (the values passed into the constructor of the `BehaviorSubject`) to an empty `Release` or something else if you wish.

```
template: `
    <h3>Release Detail</h3>
    <p>{{ release?.artist }}</p> <!-- Note the '?' -->
  `,
```

Here are the docs if you want to learn more about the different types of `Subjects`:

- [BehaviorSubject](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/subjects/behaviorsubject.md)
- [Subjects](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/gettingstarted/subjects.md)

I hope this helps!

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks, Fredrik! The RxJS concepts are still new to me so I had a feeling that is where I would have been a little off track. The only other thing I needed to change was in the ReleaseDetailComponent and ngOnInit hook --> this.release = this._releaseService.getRelease().subscribe(release=>{
            return this.release = release;
        });

Comment: Happy to help! :)

Answer (score 1):

Consider using `BehaviorSubject` as a delegate. [BehaviorSubject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39494058/angular-2-behavior-subject-vs-observable) upon a subscription returns the last value of the subject, therefore the component loaded postponely will always be updated with the recent value:

```
@Injectable
export class ReleaseService {
    releaseSource: BehaviorSubject = new BehaviorSubject(null);

   // No difference when it comes to subscribing to the BehaviorSubject
}
```

Basic example of `BehaviorSubject` in action: [Angular 2 Interaction between components
 using the service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41958836/angular-2-interaction-between-components/41960007#41960007)

Comment: Thanks, Seidme. Both yourself and Fredrik were on point. Much appreciated!

Comment: Done. Thanks, Seidme

Answer (score 0):

I think you are mixing two concepts here. There are two ways to do it:

1. In the release-detail Component you declare the `release` with `@Input` and you pass it from the release-list. The you will have it at your disposal as  variable in the component. No subject, no subscribe.
2. You use a service as above, but you already load the details. Like embed it in the release-list html, but with `*ngIf` set to false, not showing it. The when you put the selected release in your subject and it will kick off, then you can set the `*ngIf` to true, showing the release-detail part.